# Update and delete using Ajax in ASP.Net C# webservice

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

This is my code for getting data from database. It's working fine, but how can I edit, update and delete row?

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
$.ajax({
    url: 'xxxxxx/xxxxxxx',
    method: 'POST',
    datatype: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
      console.log(data);
      $('#datatable').dataTable({
        data: data,
        columns: [
          { 'data': 'UserId' },
          { 'data': 'UserDepartment' },
          { 'data': 'UserCourse' },
          { 'data': 'UserName' },
          { 'data': 'UserBirthDate' },
          { 'data': 'UserEmail' },
          { 'data': 'UserContact' }
        ]
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: i tried many codes but not working..if is there any ref. then let me know.

Comment: i am not  here to write code, so just logic only. append edit and delete buttons to the last column and when click on it fetch the unique id of row and use to edit or delete. to edit just pass the id to another page and to delete use ajax